# jquery plugin to create square-tiles with a background image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I need to split an image into square-shape tiles on which users can hover or click on.

Should i use pure css or do I have to use jquery ? Do you have examples of jquery plugins doing that? (I found [this one](http://imanish.co.in/demo/imjqmosaic/) but would be interested in other suggestions)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does "I am looking for more" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plugin is kinda old, I'd suggest you use this one, adapted from [this other plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-tiles/):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/HmpGx/

```
;(function( $, window ) {

  var _defaults = { x: 3, y: 3, gap: 2 };

  $.fn.splitInTiles = function( options ) {

    var o = $.extend( {}, _defaults, options );

    return this.each(function() {

      var $container = $(this),
          width = $container.width(),
          height = $container.height(),
          $img = $container.find('img'),
          n_tiles = o.x * o.y,
          wraps = [], $wraps;

      for ( var i = 0; i < n_tiles; i++ ) {
        wraps.push('<div class="tile"/>');
      }

      $wraps = $( wraps.join('') );
      $img.hide().after( $wraps );

      $wraps.css({
        width: (width / o.x) - o.gap,
        height: (height / o.y) - o.gap,
        marginBottom: o.gap +'px',
        marginRight: o.gap +'px',
        backgroundImage: 'url('+ $img.attr('src') +')'
      });

      $wraps.each(function() {
        var pos = $(this).position();
        $(this).css( 'backgroundPosition', -pos.left +'px '+ -pos.top +'px' );
      });

    });

  };

}( jQuery, window ));
```

Comment: What's the point of `0,0`? You can use `1,1` or `.hide()`...

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I created a new related question if you're up to it:-)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567020/optimize-rendering-speed-of-tile-grid-with-background-image-html5-dom-canvas